# The smallest nicest dense subset of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, set-theory

Let $X\not=\varnothing$ be a topological space, and $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of nonempty dense subsets of $X$. Now $\mathcal{A}$ is a poset under $\subseteq$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a chain inside $\mathcal{A}$, and consider the set:
\begin{align*}
A = \bigcap_{C \in \mathcal{C}} C
\end{align*}
Q1: Is $\overline{A}=  X$? or is $A \in \mathcal{A}$? What if $X$ is made as nice as possible, as in a locally compact Hausdorff space?

Q2: Assuming I can pick the 'maximal' chain in which an element $A' \in \mathcal{A}$ is contained, is the above at least true for that chain?

This question is motivated looking at the chain of sets $$C^n_c(\mathbb{R}) = \{f \in L^p({\mathbb{R}}): f\ \text{is}\ n\ \text{times continuously differentiable and compactly supported} \}$$ which are dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ in the $p$-norm and the Baire Category theorem; if a positive result for Q2 exists and we apply it to $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ then we might get a 'nicest and smallest' dense subspace of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ (can use it for a simpler scenario like the maximal chain for rationals in $\mathbb{R}$ as well).

I'm a bit confused as to how to approach it; it doesn't seem to hold for arbitrary kind of sets/spaces, is there an additional condition on $\mathcal{A}$ for which it can hold(for the $L^p$, consider the same collection with the additional condition that it should be a linear subspace)?

Edit:
After @Brian Moehring's nice answer, I have made the following addendum:

Q3: If $\mathcal{L}$ is a collection of linear subspaces of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that are dense under the p norm, then it is also a poset under $\subseteq$. If $\mathcal{C}$ denotes a chain in this poset, is it true that $\cap_{C \in \mathcal{C}} C \in \mathcal{L}$?

(If we so we could take a maximal chain containing the subspaces which consist of equivalence classes of continuous functions and obtain a nice small dense subset)

Comment: For a maximal chain, I think all you can say is that $\bar{A}$ contains the isolated points of $X$.  There's definitely no reason we'd have $\bar{A}=X$ (in fact, even for $X=[0,1]$, you may have $\bar{A} = \emptyset$)

Comment: Let $X=[0,1]$, and $C_n$ be the set of dyadic number whose minimal denominator is at least $2^n$. Then every $C_n$ is dense, the family $(C_n)$ is non-increasing (so is a chain) but its intersection is empty.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Is the restriction to imposing linear subspaces in $L^p$ not enough to give such a set?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $X$ is Fréchet ($T_1$), the following holds (prove it if you need to do so):

> If $A \subset X$ is dense and $x\in A$ is not an isolated point of $X$, then $A \setminus \{x\} \subset X$ is dense.

Assuming $X$ has no isolated points, this means that a maximal chain of dense subsets of $X$ cannot have a minimum element, so whenever your $\mathcal{C}$ is maximal, the intersection $\bigcap\mathcal{C}$ is not dense.

Comment: What if we impose the additional structure in $\mathcal{A}$ of being a linear subspace when we are dealing with something like $L^p$? Then we can't remove arbitrary points right?

Comment: @RohanDidmishe If the subsets you're intersecting have more structure, then you're asking a different question, so the answer would be different, but I think you're going to run into the same problem.  If you have a dense subspace strictly smaller that $X$ itself, then I expect some codim 1 subspace of that dense subspace to still be dense (this isn't a proof, since some analogue of isolated points should still appear, but it's a strong feeling)

Comment: @RohanDidmishe To negate my "strong feeling" from the last comment:  If $X$ has a Schauder basis $B$, then the span of $B$ will be a dense subspace $A \subseteq X$ such that no proper subspace of $A$ is dense in $X$.  This provides a partial answer to the modified question, but, as not every separable Banach space even has a Schauder basis, I'm not sure how to go farther.